# I want to use Twilio in my app so I can make a call in South Korea

Tags: api, twilio

I am trying to make an app that makes calls using the phone call api. This is not an international call, but a domestic call.

I live in South Korea. Around 400 phone numbers are required, and the number format should not be international. Is it possible in Twilio? I don't know where can I ask.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First you have to [buy a Twilio phone number in the Republic Of Korea](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/search/buy/results?Country=KR&searchType=number&searchTerm=&align=left&capability%5B%5D=any&type%5B%5D=any&requirement%5B%5D=any&beta%5B%5D=true).

[image: South Korean phone numbers]

You can see that these South Korean numbers shown all have voice capabilities. You'll need to use [the Twilio REST API to make outbound calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls). That link shows you how to make calls via curl request, Java, Python, Node.js and other languages as well. In Python, that will look something like this:

```
from twilio.rest import Client


# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = 'YOUR-ACCOUNT-SID'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                        url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
                        to='NUMBER-TO-CALL',
                        from_='YOUR-TWILIO-NUMBER'
                    )
print(call.sid)
```

Node.js would look something like

```
const accountSid = 'your-account-sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
      .create({
         url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
         to: 'NUMBER-TO-CALL',
         from: 'YOUR-TWILIO-NUMBER'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

And the curl would look something like

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/YOUR-ACCOUNT-SID/Calls.json \
--data-urlencode "Url=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml" \
--data-urlencode "To=NUMBER-TO-CALL" \
--data-urlencode "From=+YOUR-TWILIO-NUMBER" \
-u ACd7546b9ed2055fe55ee4209bb3043591:your_auth_token
```

You'll need to loop through the phone numbers you wish to make a call to, replacing NUMBER-TO-CALL above with each one. You may be reading from a .txt file or array, but will need to loop through it in whichever programming language you prefer.

Comment: does twilio still support South Korea? I cannot search any Korean phone numbers